# `package` does not delete old version on update

Tags: package

Whenever `package` updates a package in Emacs 24.4, and it asks me if I want to delete the previous version, it fails to do so even when I answer `y`. It gives me the following message:

```
Delete package `rich-minority-20140821.2020'? (y or n) y
Renaming
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm using GNU Emacs 24.4.1, on Debian 7.7 and I wasn't able to reproduce. The deletion was effective after the update. Is there something special/interesting in your `*Messages*` buffer?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an advice gone rogue. Do you, by any chance, use an advice regarding file deletion?

Comment: In any case, try to reproduce this with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @Nsukami_ No, just the message I posted above.

Comment: @Malabarba No, no advice on that. I will try your suggestion and report.

Comment: @Malabarba The problem is that I could not try the update package procedure starting with `emacs -Q`.  When I start it that way, I get no updates available. Any further ideas?

Comment: @NVaughan make it work. Using emacs -Q, evaluate the configuration which adds your package archives (probably melpa). And then you should have some upgrades available.

Comment: @NVaughan There's probably an advice on `delete-directory`.

Comment: @lunaryorn How can I check that? There's nothing in my init files.

Comment: `C-h f` shows you advises on the function.  And it's probably that we should *see* your init files know, because your issue is most probably caused by a mis-configuration or a faulty package in your init file.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of Malabarba and lunaryon, I noticed this piece of code that was blocking the `delete-directory` function:

```
 (setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t
       trash-directory "~/.Trash/emacs")
```

I commented it and everything works fine now.

---

**Update:**

After trying a recommendation from `Emacswiki`, the following works fine:

```
 (setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)
  (defun system-move-file-to-trash (file)
    "Use \"trash\" to move FILE to the system trash.
  When using Homebrew, install it using \"brew install trash\"."
    (call-process (executable-find "trash")
      nil 0 nil
      file))
```

Comment: I don't think that this should break `package-delete`.  You don't happen to use [trash-settings.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/trash-settings.el), do you?

Comment: @lunaryorn No, I don't.